# VBA Paste Range Values into last row

Tags: excel, row, copy-paste, vba

What I am trying to do is copy the values in E17:BK17 into the last row. Right now with what I have all it copies is the Value of E17 into the last row, but not the remaining columns data into the last row. Any help would be appreciated since I don't really know what I'm doing.

```
Sub Mercy_CopyPaste_Row()
'
' CopyPaste Macro
'
'
Dim targetRng As Excel.Range
Dim destRng As Excel.Range
Set targetRng = Range("$E$17:$BK$17")
Set destRng = Excel.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

destRng.Value = targetRng.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Your destRng is 1 column, you need to Resize it to targetRng.Columns.Count

Comment: You can find your answer by getting help from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Set targetRng = Range("$E$17:$BK$17")` is 59 columns, while `destRng = Excel.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` is a single column (actually it's a single cell). That's the reason you are only pasting a single cell "E17".

In order for your `destRng` to be the same size of `targetRng` (same number of columns), you need to `Resize` the range to `targetRng.Columns.Count`.

Try the code below:

```
Set destRng = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, targetRng.Columns.Count)
destRng.Value = targetRng.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you're looking for

```
Sub Mercy_CopyPaste_Row()

 Dim lRow As Long
 Dim ACell As String
 Dim Col As String
 Dim targetRng As Excel.Range
 Set targetRng = Range("$E$17:$BK$17")
 lRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row)
 ACell = Range("E17").Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

 Range("$E$17:$BK$17").AutoFill Range(ACell & ":" & "BK" & lRow)

 End Sub
```

Comment: almost worked but it overwrote everything in the previous columns